# How can I make multiple markers on a map clickable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I'm trying to put multiple clickable markers on a Google Map but am having issues finding a way to do it. The code examples online all refer to arrays where the data is held, but all  I want to do is make the map zoom in to the one that is clicked.

The location data is filled in by wordpress in a while loop so that posts can automatically add new locations to the global map.

Easy enough, but with my code it only works with the last one. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024,-95.712891),
        disableDefaultUI: true,
    };

    var posts = locationLat.length;
    var j = 0;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
    var place = new Array();

        while (posts != j)
        {
            var image = '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/location_marker.png';
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locationLat[j],locationLong[j]);

            place[j] = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                icon: image
            });   

            google.maps.event.addListener(place[j], 'click', function() {
            map.setZoom(8);
            map.setCenter(myLatLng);

            $('.sidebar').stop().animate({
                'width' : '400px',
                'opacity' : '1'
            }, 500);
            });
            j++;
        }
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Really not sure as all the other examples online don't really do this. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: image
}); 
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   map.setZoom(8);
   map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found what I was looking for:

```
map.panTo(this.getPosition());
```

This seems to work perfectly.